# MySQL: SUBTIME() without negative values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I need to compare two intervals of time. The problem is that the interval can vary from 09:00:00 to 02:00:00. When you try to fetch rows for this period none will show up since the start time is bigger than the end time.

So I thought if I subtract 3 hours from each value I work with then the query would work. The period range will be 06:00:00 - 23:00:00 and end time will always be bigger than start time.

However, I tried to do it with SUBTIME() but as the documentation states 02:00:00 - 03:00:00 is -01:00:00 where I need it to be 23:00:00.

Is this possible and how can it be achieved?

I am open for any other solutions, so here's the "real world" issue:

I have a table with bowling reservations, they all start somewhere between 9 in the morning and 2 after midnight, they also have an end time also between this period. I need to make a search and allow the client to say for which interval of time would he/she like to see the reservations. So, he/she should be able to search for reservations that begin and end between 23:00 and 02:00 for example. So I say that the reservation start time should be >= than the search start time and the reservation end time should be <= than the search end time. Which is perfectly fine as algorithm, except that for MySQL 23:00 is just bigger than 02:00.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to store your data differently.  Modify it before it enters the table, don't try to frig things when you query the data.  You need to make sure that your end time actually is greater than your start time.  Storing the data as a DateTime will allow that.

Answer (score 2):

Try storing the period end points as datetime values (rather than time).

Then use timediff or timestampdiff on the result.

Wow, supervisors should hire people with the right skills to design software and then listen to them, but that is besides the point.

You can still do what you want.  As a subquery add the following two variables:

```
(case when start < '4:00:00' then dateadd('2000-01-02 00:00:00', start)
      else dateadd('1900-01-01 00:00:00', start
 end) as startwithday
(case when end < '4:00:00' then dateadd('2000-01-01 00:00:00', end )
      else dateadd('1900-01-01 00:00:00', end 
 end) as endwithday
```

These convert times to times on Jan 1 or Jan 2 in the year 2000.  This is an arbitrary date, but now you can do the difference calculations on these fields.

Comment: I cannot store as datetime becouse both values clearly state that they should hold time. Since it is a reservation period (x o'clock till y o'clock). There is no logical explanation why I should store datetime and therefore my supervisor wont let me.